# Why does the following Facebook fql query is not returning any data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

```
SELECT uid, name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid in(256178797901718) and rsvp_status='attending') order by name
```

The purpose of the query is to get all the users' ID, name and sex who are all attending for a Facebook event.

Is there any other way to try with Graph API instead?

> Facebook API Version : 2.0
>
> Event ID : 256178797901718

I have tried other ways by removing rsvp_status condition, I am getting users data except sex.

Answer (score 0):

FQL is deprecated, you should not use it anymore. This would be the correct endpoint for the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/attending/

I don´t think it is possible to get the gender though, i just tried with an example call and the gender is not in the result: `/[event-id]/attending?fields=id,name,gender`

Comment: I have tried Graph API using the following - [Graph API link](https://graph.facebook.com/256178797901718/attending?fields=id,name,gender&access_token=48654146645|UTrkZdHI8EPmvWeWKw-IaKP7cfk). But still no use, I am not getting the "gender" field

Comment: please read my answer again, i did state that it´s most likely impossible to get the gender field for attending users.

Comment: Sorry, just saw that. So it is not possible at all?

Comment: if it´s not in the result, then most likely it´s not possible at all, no

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the request syntax – it is a permissions issue.

Requesting the `gender` field requires `public_profile` permission – and users would have to log into your app and grant it that permission, before you can get the value.

You can easily test this with an event you are yourself attending:

Login to your app (that grants `public_profile` permission by default for web login), then request the list of users attending the event using `/[event-id]/attending?fields=id,name,gender` as luschn already suggested in their answer – and you will see, that for your own account, the gender field is returned (and for other users attending the event that have logged in to your app before, if there are any) – but for everyone else it simply won’t be returned.